# Syncing dropbox folder accross dual boot

Tags: windows, linux, sync, dropbox

I'm dual booting windows and linux. My dropbox folder is currently installed via windows. On linux, can I just symlink my dropbox folder to the windows version or something to that effect? I know I can do it, but is there a way to do this and still have the daemon running and syncing correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just symlink my dropbox folder to the windows version or something to that effect

Yes, you can do so.

> but is there a way to do this and still have the daemon running and syncing correctly?

I'm not sure I understand, mount the Windows partition, install Dropbox in linux and symlink the Dropbox directory to the Windows directory and it will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Just ensure your Windows partition is mounted at boot via fstab before the dropbox daemon is running.

A typical `fstab` NTFS mount using the ntfs-3g driver would look like so:

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt ntfs-3g defaults,force 0 0
```