# Dual boot and Dropbox

Tags: multi-boot, sync, ntfs, dropbox, ext4

I dual boot on my laptop:

- Ubuntu Mate 18.04 LTS
- Windows 10

I've set up Dropbox in both operating systems. I'm not actually syncing the Dropbox twice -- as my Dropbox is quite large, this would be wasteful in terms of bandwidth and disk space. Therefore, similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/182727/144394), I mount the Windows NTFS drive in Linux and tell the Linux Dropbox client that it should use that location.

This has worked fine for years. However, Dropbox [has recently announced](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/system-requirements?oref=e#desktop) that onwards from November 7<sup>th</sup>, 2018, they're demanding that the Dropbox Folder is located on:

- `ext4` when in Linux
- `NTFS` when in Windows

That means that my current set-up will break. However, I simply don't have the disk space to duplicate the Dropbox folder, nor do I want to spend bandwidth on syncing data that's essentially already in sync...

I've spoken with a Dropbox representative, and they're "very sorry, but". So, I'm looking for a viable workaround.

- Is there a way to "fake" `ext4`-ism on an `NTFS` drive in Linux?
- Or the other way round (hahahanoway)?
- ...I'm actually all out of ideas on this one.

The email reminder I've been receiving over the past few months:

[image]

Comment: You do know, your links says while it's a requirement, your current setup will continue to work.  Have you confirmed the current version of Dropbox no longer functions in your current configuration?  I see no mention of November 7th on your reference page. As far as I can see, those requirements, are the current requirements

Comment: @Ramhound see edit. The representative confirmed that Dropbox on Linux will stop syncing after this date, unless I make these changes

Comment: @Ramhound actually, the text I linked to is a bit ambiguous; it says _as a sub-point of the `ext4` requirement_ that other "supported" file systems will continue to work. Considering everything, I'm inclined to interpret that as "it won't work unless you switch to `ext4`"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I've just solved this problem... My solution is:
1. Download and sync the Dropbox first under Windows;
2. Boot Ubuntu, and install the ntfs-3g and mount the partition containing your Dropbox folder;
3. Create a symbolic link of the Dropbox folder from your NTFS partition to your ext4 partition (anywhere you like);
4. Open the Dropbox in Ubuntu and set the folder path as the symbolic link you just created;
5. Enjoy it!

Comment: interesting...I always assumed the Dropbox deamon would complain. I now realize I've never actually tested it! I'll certainly give this a try

Comment: Does not work on Debian (Dropbox client version 106.4.368). Says, "Unexpected errors occurred. Your Dropbox is ok!" (sic)